# textfield content in an iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As iam new the iphone development, i had created some textfields ,on click of save button it gets saved to a xml file ,and get disappears in the text field.On the next login, how to get the previously entered data in the same text field,so that i can modify the same data entered in the previous log in

thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a certain reason you are using an xml file?  If not take a look at NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Read the xml file and set this to the textfield, textfield.text = @"your String";

Answer (score 0):

To get previously entered data, you have to save them.
For this when user tap on save button you can save the value of each text field to NSUserDefaults for a key and when you want to get data you can get for that key.

To save-

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[textfield text] forKey:@"username"];

To get -

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *str = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];